# List comprehension for a dictionary?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a quite simple problem, but I am not able to solve it.

I have to pass a dictionary to a function like this:

```
session.run(
    output_names=[_input.name for _input in session.get_outputs()],
    input_feed={
        "input_ids": inputs["input_ids"],
        "attention_mask": inputs["attention_mask"],
        "token_type_ids": inputs["token_type_ids"],
    },
)
```

For the output_names it´s quite easy, but how can I do this for the input_feed? Is it possible to convert this:

```
empty = {}
for _input in inputs:
    empty[_input] = _input
```

into a oneliner?

Comment: This is a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary comprehension is indeed a thing and works like you might expect. For example:

`empty = {x: x for x in inputs}`

Comment: Or `empty = dict(inputs, inputs)`